# Crossing border from India to Myanmar

Tags: india, myanmar

I know that India–Myanmar–Thailand Trilateral Highway is still under construction and may become operational later this year. However I came to know that it is still possible to cross the India–Myanmar border from Moreh, Manipur on Indian side. Is it safe to plan a road trip to Mandalay, Myanmar from India by crossing the border in Moreh? Is there any security risks involved for an Indian citizen?

Comment: What security risks are you afraid of?

Comment: @JoErNanO Myanmar has seen several ongoing armed conflicts between the government and insurgency groups. As per Wikipedia the conflict has been described as one of the world's "longest running civil wars". So for a foreign national traveler I was particular concerned about such activities. Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conflict_in_Myanmar

Comment: So once again: what are you afraid of? Being shot? Losing your passport? I'm just trying to narrow this down to make it answerable on Travel.

Comment: @JoErNanO First of all I want to know whether it is still possible to cross the border legally at Moreh, Manipur. Secondly if it is possible to cross the border, while travelling to Mandalay via road is it probable that I might run into such insurgency groups? What sort of precautions I should take to avoid such incident?

Comment: Please add more details to your question then.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of people go to Namphalong for shopping every day without a visa/passport. It is a porous border unlike the Indo-Pak border where even a flying pigeon is shot down some times due to suspicion. I wont recomend doing this , just wanted you to know that hundreds of people do that every day and it will stop one day.

You can cross the border at Moreh into Tamu if you have the required documents.

Security risk?  If you are not a Manipuri native you have a security risk on our side of the border too not just in Myanmar. There are lots of insurgents on both sides of the border not just in Myanmar side. Yes there is a security risk there.

There was a trial run for Imphal to Mandalay bus service in Dec 2015 but regular bus service has not started yet.

Comment: According to Ministry of Imimgration & Population (http://www.mip.gov.mm/portfolio/types-of-visa-fees-and-duration/), entry to Myanmar is only via 3 international airports. Is there any other overland border crossing?